# sticky footer with angular directives, routes, material

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-routing, angular-material

I am trying to implement the classical sticky footer. I am using angular 1.4, ngRoute, ngMaterial etc. 
I have tried css solutions (setting wrapper, footer, html, body 100%) and also jQuery functions that calculate the height of the element, but nothing works flawlessly. Note here that I don't want to set a certain height for the footer and then calculate the remaining space. I want it to be responsive to my content.

1) We most solutions, I am able to stick it to the bottom **when the main content area is smaller that the height**. In this case, there is an empty area between the main content and the footer (body). I can set the body's background color equal to the color of the ng-view so that it looks the same. I am not sure though if this is correct.

2) **When the main content gets bigger, the footer is lost** (goes behind the main content instead of scrolling down). Does this has anything to do with angular directives or routes, or am I missing something else?
You can check my [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/74X9eOwT1SCBr7VgloG5) to see. Click on any tab other than 'home' and you see an empty page with the footer on bottom. Click on 'home' and the footer is lost. It is actually there, behind the content. 
p.s. I don't want to put all my code here it's pretty big. If you have any questions please see plunkr or ask me.

```
<body class="Site" ng-app="personalWebsite" ng-controller="mainController as main" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap;">

<div class="Site-content">
    <tsafou-nav></tsafou-nav>

    <md-content layout-padding ng-view></md-content>
</div>

<footer>
    <tsafou-footer></tsafou-footer>
</footer>

</body>
```

*Footer

```
<div class="footer">
    <p>Design by<span>WOW</span></p>
</div>
```

I just realized that the following code works on firefox but not on chrome! Can someone confirm that and suggest a fix?

```
<body class="Site" ng-app="personalWebsite" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap;">
<div class="Site-content">
  <tsafou-nav></tsafou-nav>
  <md-content layout-padding="" ng-view=""></md-content>
</div>
<footer>
  <tsafou-footer></tsafou-footer>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is using bootstrap sticky footer
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

Answer (score 0):

It's related to the Angular Material library you are using, which relies on Flexbox. Review [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) site for how to add a footer using the Flexbox framework.

To easily fix your problem, you can move the footer within the div class that has the 'site-content' class. If you want to have some empty space, you can try setting a div outside that has a min height. So it would look like this:

```
 <body class="Site" ng-app="personalWebsite" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap;">
    <div class="Site-content">
      <tsafou-nav></tsafou-nav>
      <div  style="min-height: 500px;">
      <md-content layout-padding="" ng-view=""></md-content>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <tsafou-footer></tsafou-footer>
    </footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: None of the solutions seems to work. If I put the footer inside the "Site-content" without the div with set height, I just get a footer at the end of the main text. If I use the min-height, then it's no longer responsive. This number depends on the screen height.
The bootstrap sticky footer does not help either. It sets the footer to the end, but when more content is added to the main text, the footer gets lost behind that main content. Any thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean it's no longer responsive? the min height should set the default height so that the footer isn't directly underneath the nav, but it should grow vertically as needed. if you plan to use the bootstrap library, you will need to use bootstrap's responsive framework for it to work. there are several angular compatible bootstrap implementations - i would explore those if you go the bootstrap route.

Comment: Maybe you missed my edit on my main post. I said that this works on firefox but not on chrome. On firefox the footer is at the bottom and as the main content grows the footer scrolls down. On chrome on the other hand, the footer starts at the bottom but goes behind the main content as it grows... Any thoughts?

Comment: hmm I was actually using chrome when I was doing it on the plunkr. is it maybe a caching issue? in order for my method to work though, you have to wrap the md-content in a div that holds the min-height property, otherwise you'll encounter the same issue. (I just noticed you updated your plunk)

Comment: the footer also has to be within the 'site' class object.

Comment: I still cant get it to work correctly on chrome. Tried setting min-height on the div holding the md-content, and also putting footer within the 'site' (and also 'site-content' objects. Is it possible that you show me your plunkr or modify mine as needed?